# how to read and edit keystore and truststore for secured connection?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I want to change my openfire server from http to https protocol. So it asks for RSA and DSA certificates. By default openfire generating self signed certificates. But they are not supporting to work after connecting openfire with IJab client in my spring based java application.
and I want to read the generated keystore and trust store in openfire. How can I do that.?
can any one please help me to solve this?